# Excluding directory when using tar

Tags: unix, tar

I have quite a simple bash script that's running every night via crontab.

The issue I am having is ignoring one of the directories when archiving up my site using tar. It still seems to include it.

Any thoughts?

```
#!/bin/bash

NOW=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H%M")

DB_USER=""
DB_PASS=""
DB_NAME=""
DB_HOST=""

TREE_FILE="$NOW.tar.gz"
DB_FILE="$DB_NAME.$NOW.sql"

BACKUP_DIR="/var/www/html/site/backups/"
WWW_DIR="/var/www/html/site/"

mkdir -p $BACKUP_DIR
tar -czvf $BACKUP_DIR/$TREE_FILE --exclude=/var/www/html/site/backups/ $WWW_DIR

mysqldump -h$DB_HOST -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PASS $DB_NAME > $BACKUP_DIR/$DB_FILE

find $BACKUP_DIR -type f -mtime +7 -delete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe tar strips any trailing slashes from directory paths, so I think you simply want to leave the trailing slash off your pattern:

```
tar -czvf $BACKUP_DIR/$TREE_FILE --exclude=/var/www/html/site/backups $WWW_DIR
```

This will exclude the directory `backups` and everything below it, but not (for example) a file named `backupsthing`.

You could also do something like this:

```
tar -czvf $BACKUP_DIR/$TREE_FILE --exclude="/var/www/html/site/backups/*" $WWW_DIR
```

This would include the `backups` dir itself, but nothing under it. (I.e., you'd have an empty dir in the tar.)

Comment: This worked a treat. Many thanks! Should I remove the trailing slash from BACKUP_DIR and WWW_DIR then too?

Comment: Don't think it matters in either of those cases, but note that you've got a trailing slash on `BACKUP_DIR` **and** an explicit slash in `$BACKUP_DIR/$TREE_FILE`, so I'd probably remove them if for nothing other than pedantry.

Comment: Perfect. Much appreciated response :)